# Hellsing soundtrack − Unexpected incident

Tags: music, hellsing

Among the tracks of Hellsing's OST albums there is one that abruptly ends at about 1 minute mark and it is called "Unexpected incident". I couldn't find a full version (if it even exists) and I'm starting to suspect that this actually is the fullest version, and it's called like that as a joke. Comments to youtube videos suggest the same, but I don't trust them.

Is there any official confirmation that this is indeed the whole track, or is there a longer version somewhere?

*One of the many youtube videos:* http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XL0fFXO8apM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the track is #22 on [the RUINS album](http://vgmdb.net/album/22219) (in Japanese, the track is titled 「予期せぬ出来事」 *Yoki Senu Dekigoto*). The associated album scans don't have track lengths printed on them, but the enterprising user who entered the track listing on VGMdb indicated that the track was 0:59 in length.

I figure that's probably the whole track. [Some random Japanese reviewer](http://nippori-friedrice.com/anime/review/Hellsing_2.php) also lists it as 0:59, for independent corroboration.

(There's an amusing annotation beneath the track list on the poster that basically says "Per the intent of the composer, this recording includes noise and unexpected sounds". I suppose, then, that an unexpected *lack* of sound is not too far beyond the pale.)